# Reconciling phase shift error of length-tuned structures in 81-86GHz I/Q direct down-converter ASIC with datasheet specifications

Tags: rf, microwave, reverse-engineering, phase-shift, asic

I'm watching [a video on reverse engineering a GaAs 81-86GHz I/Q down-converter ASIC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2c-02V7fuMY). The relevant section of the video for this question is 10 minutes onwards, but watching the video isn't necessary for answering this question. The IC in question is an [ADI HMC7587](https://www.analog.com/en/products/hmc7587.html).

To start out, here's the full die shot with the RF and LO inputs and I/Q differential outputs marked:

[image: Microscope image of an HMC7587 81GHz to 86GHz I/Q downconverter IC die.]

The LO input on the bottom left is fed into a series of frequency multipliers and amplifiers to produce a 6x frequency multiplication. This forms a mixing frequency in the 81-86GHz range, matching the frequency of the RF input.

The RF input on the top right is fed into a Wilkinson divider, which splits the signal into two equal copies for mixing for the \$I\$ and \$Q\$ sides of the circuit. The \$I\$ and \$Q\$ mixers are both differential, so the outputs are IFIP/IFIN for \$I\$, and IFQP/IFQN for \$Q\$.

Here's an annotated close-up of the phase generation and mixing section:

[image: Close-up of the I/Q differential phase generation and mixing section of the ASIC. The LO frequency is multiplied by 6 to form an 81-86GHz input signal for the section being analysed. The signal goes into the input of a Lange coupler, which is marked as being a quarter wavelength in size. The isolated port has an RC structure attached. The direct port is marked as outputting input minus zero degrees phase. The coupled port is marked as outputting in minus 90 degrees phase. Each of these phases goes to a single-to-differential converter structure (a Balun) with a size of roughly half a wavelength. These each introduce a 180 degree phase shift on top of the input phase shift. The top differential output has 0 and -180 degrees phase, and the bottom differential output has -270 and -90 degrees phase.]

The way I understand it, the Lange coupler produces a phase shift of -90° on its coupled port vs. the direct port, and this phase shift arises due to a propagation delay, which is tuned based on \$\frac λ 4\$ at the midpoint frequency. The structure on the isolated port absorbs signal reflections due to any mismatch.

The 0° and -90° phase copies are then each fed to a single-ended-to-differential coupler (a Balun?) which introduces an additional 180° of phase shift to each signal. This is achieved by tuning the length of the coupler to \$\frac λ 2\$.

Measuring phase shift from the top downwards (i.e. referenced to IFIP) we get 0° and -180° for the differential \$I\$ output, then -270° and -90° for the differential \$Q\$ output.

The datasheet claims a typical phase balance error of ±4° across the specified 81-86GHz range. However, if the coupler structures are sized based on quarter and half wavelengths at the center frequency of 83.5GHz, surely the phase balance error must be in excess of ±5°?

The percentage calculation is:

$$\left( \frac {83.5} {81} - \frac {83.5} {86} \right) \times 100 \approx 6 \% $$

Which means a ±3% phase error on all length-matched structures. Therefore there must be a differential phase error of ±5.4° (±3% of 180°) and an I-Q phase error of ±2.7° (±3% of 90°). Where does their ±4° figure come from?

It strikes me as oddly coincidental that the average of these two phase errors is almost exactly ±4°, but I can't see why they would use the average.